# C / C++ - How to download byte by byte (like a file stream) from the web?

Tags: c++, c, url, download, stream

I'm building a simple download and file transfer manager in C and C++, with support for pause and resume operations.
I looked for a way to download byte by byte from a given URL, but all I could find were references to external libraries like libcurl. I don't want external libraries, I want to manually read and write the bytes in a similar way used to read and write bytes to files (like ifstream in C++, and fopen in C) using only the C/C++ native library.
The pseudo-code for what I need would be:

```
void download(file, url) {
    file.open();
    url.open();
    set_active(true);
    while( ! pause() ) {
        bytes_read = url.read(byte_array);
        if(bytes_read < 1)
            break;
        file.write(byte_array, bytes_read);
    }
    url.close();
    file.close();
    set_active(false);
}
```

How would that pseudo-code work in both C and C++?

---

EDIT: I don't want external libraries for the simple interest on learning the capabilities and limits of both languages and their native libraries.

EDIT 2: Conclusion: Neither of the languages have native support for HTTP operations, therefore I have to choose between a using third-party library or writing a HTTP (and several other protocols) implementation from the scratch, which is unreliable. Thanks.

Comment: There is no networking support in C or C++ standard libraries. You cannot avoid using *some* third-party library. There is no shortage of those.

Comment: You can create a socket, call `connect()` and then `read()` from the socket, it's not simple though, and using a library like `curl` would make your life a lot easier, for example suppose that you had to use `ssl` for a `https` connection, then it would be really hard to write robust feature complete code, instead `libcurl` would help you do that and more. Also, with `curl` you don't need to deal with port numbers and with how many Ip's `getaddrinfo()` returned and which one works, for a `https` you just give the `url` and `curl` will know the port and do evertything for you.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I would consider sockets api to be "standard" as in it exists on all major platforms. He does not need some third party library for that. He needs what his platform has to offer. If he wants to use sockets for loading via http he might want to find apis above raw socket layer though. Most operating systems also have "os specific" standard APIs for that.

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain why you don't want third party HTTP libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) or some other [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) client library (e.g. [libsoup](https://developer.gnome.org/libsoup/stable/) if using GTK). If you need HTTP server support, you can find libraries for that, e.g. [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/).

You might also consider [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) or [Qt5](http://qt.io/) frameworks, they both have HTTP things.

If you don't want to use any such HTTP 3<sup>rd</sup> party libraries, you'll need to re-implement HTTP by yourself. That might be complex (and several months or years of work), since the HTTP specifications are several hundreds pages! Handling some simplistic `GET` requests is easy, but handing all the HTTP specification is hard.

<sup>You could try to implement your *subset* of HTTP which *might* work in *some* cases, but you'll easily find HTTP servers or clients needing more of HTTP, .... And your implementation would be much more brittle and buggy than existing HTTP libraries...</sup>

Comment: you also have the gnome libsoup librairy for dealing with http request response

Comment: I doubt that would use months or years of work to get something done quickly. My guess would be 3 hours for the first successful GET. What will be nasty in the end is https and certificates etc. But for a non-secure HTTP connection it is not that much work.

Comment: Indeed, but when you'll need chunked requests, conditional ones, etc... things will become complex.

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed your edited requirement that you don't want external libraries. But here are extracts from a program I wrote in MSVC to download files from a Windows program.

```
// Windows Header Files:
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>

// Make internet connection.
HINTERNET hInternetSession = InternetOpen(
        "Microsoft Internet Explorer",          // agent
        INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,           // access
        NULL, NULL, 0);                         // defaults
...

// Make connection to desired page.
HINTERNET hURL = InternetOpenUrl(
        hInternetSession,                       // session handle
        szSors,                                 // URL to access
        NULL, 0, 0, 0);                         // defaults
if (hURL == 0)
    return 0;
...

// Read data into memory buffer.
DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
BOOL bResult = InternetReadFile(
        hURL,                                   // handle to URL
        (LPSTR)cBuffer,                         // pointer to buffer
        (DWORD)MYBSIZE,                         // size of buffer
        &dwBytesRead);                          // to hold return value
...

InternetCloseHandle(hInternetSession);
```

I never downloaded one byte as you ask, but I don't see why you could not.